# Android Eclipse debugging not working properly

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am using eclipse with real phone Samsung Galaxy nexus, when I try to debug my service, I put breakpoints but debugger stops in wrong lines... I mean it even stops at comment lines etc...

What I did to solve:

- I tested in another samsung phone same problem
- I uninstalled and installed again adb and android device

but still debugging wrong lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that your last source code was not correctly compiled and installed on the device (you may have unintentionally unchecked `Build automatically` option). Some things you can try:

- Do a full clean of your project.
- Uninstall application on device.
- Reinstall and run in debug on mode again.